# What's the difference between metaphor and conceptual blending?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, language, anthropology

A "metaphor" seems to be just the discourse-level result of a conceptual blend. If you're more of a Lakoff-guy, I could see you claiming "metaphor", especially a "conceptual metaphor" to be the same as a conceptual blend. However, I'm not sure if this claim is wrong. Is there a large difference between these two concepts?

Comment: What is a "conceptual blend"? What is "Lakoff" claiming about these concepts?